# How do you create a relative image link w/ GitHub Flavored Markdown?

Tags: github-flavored-markdown

I'm working with GFM for a series of Github wikis that will need to function across repos. I have no issue embedded relative images `[[/path/to/image.png]]` or creating relative links `[[Link Text|Relative-link]]`, but I've not been able to figure out how to combine the two to create a link out of the image. Any ideas?

The output I'm looking for is:

```
<a href="/path/to/link">
    <img src="/path/to/image.png" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Two ways of doing it:

1. Using a reference link

   ```
   [[[/images/gravatar.jpeg]]][1]
   [1]: http://www.inf.ufrgs.br
   ```
2. Using a link directly

   ```
   [[[/images/gravatar.jpeg]]](http://www.inf.ufrgs.br)
   ```

The logic behind is that we use double brackets to wrap an image and one extra to wrap a link. [Here](https://github.com/gabrieloshiro/markdown/wiki/Home) is an example.